# jsr-303 exclued some elements from list during validation

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have class like this:

```
class From{
    private List<SubForm> subForms;
}

class SubForm{

    @NotBlank
    String name;

    @Max(value=100)
    Integer count;
    ...
    public boolen isValidatable(){
        ....
    }
}
```

I need to validate list of subForms inside Form, but I want to exclude element that return isValidatable=false. 
I cannot chage Form object before Validator.validate() method. I can use standard annotations or write my own ConstraintValidator. 
how can I do it better ?

Answer (score 0):

I find solution.
I created my own annotation and add it above List I want validate

```
@ConditionallyValidatedListItems
private List<ConditionallyValidated> subforms = new ArrayList<>();
```

then when I create ConstraintValidator. I get validator inside isValide method and if it necessary validate item

```
Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
//get item check if it necessry to validte it    
Set<ConstraintViolation<ConditionallyValidated>> validate = validator.validate(conditionallyValidated);
```

I create example on the github 
https://github.com/YaroslavTir/jsr303-ConditionallyValidatedListItems